# tslint proper error/warning handling

Tags: webpack, tslint

Our project uses Webpack and tslint.

*Expected:*

I want tslint errors to produce build errors, and tslint warnings to produce just console warnings.

*Actual:*

If we set `emitErrors` to `true` in config, any tslint error/warning will produce error.

If `emitErrors` is `false`, any tslint error/warning will not produce error.

How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this particular issue. I wanted to have lint warnings not cause the build to fail but errors to cause it to fail.

I forked the tslint-loader repo and added a couple of new options:

- failOnError: bool
- failOnWarning: bool

So you can use either, or both, or none. Pretty useful!

The Fork:
https://github.com/gunn4r/tslint-loader

Answer (score 1):

***tslint-loader***

The symptom you describe is caused by [tslint-loader](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader), not `tslint` itself.

All linting violations (warning or error) are emitted to webpack in one big lump.  In other words, the results of the linting are represented by a single string.  This string is emitted either as a warning or as an error.

Therefore, `emitErrors` really means "emit all violations as an error".  The default is to "emit all violations as a warning".  There isn't an option to emit warnings as warnings and errors as errors.

[This fork of tslint-loader](https://github.com/mikepatrick/tslint-loader) demonstrates how you might make it perform the way you want.  It will fail the build if there are any errors, and display the errors.  If there are warnings only, the build will succeed and the warnings will be displayed.

To try it out:

```
"tslint-loader": "github:mikepatrick/tslint-loader",
```

***Linting separately***

This limitation is part of the reason that I prefer to run linting separately (outside of webpack) as part of my build process.

For example, if you do something like `yarn lint && yarn build` instead of just `yarn build`, the build will fail on any linting errors but pass if there are only warnings.  The second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818736/add-flow-to-compilation-step-on-create-react-app-project/46855615#46855615) details how to do this with flow; you could do the same thing with tslint:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server.....",
    "build:prod": "lint && webpack src/index.js dist/bundle.js -p",
    "lint": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\tslint src\\**\\*.ts*"
  },
```

This way running `yarn build:prod` will fail if there are linting errors, but pass if there are only warnings.